# What to do about a colleague who likes to embarrass you?

Tags: communication, colleagues

Over time I became friends with a colleague who is the assistant of my manager. We are not in the same team but we have to communicate at work. I have noticed that when we are outside of work (ex: eating dinner together etc.) or we are alone, she is nice to me. But when we need to talk at work or in a group, she contradicts me,  tries to prove me wrong, and makes personal comments (about weight or age, for example). I think this affects my manager's personal opinions about me.

I tried to talk to her about it, but she denied it. I don't want to be friends with this person anymore because of her behavior, and I don't want to bring this situation up at the workplace because it is personal.

What steps can a person take to shift an unhealthy friendly relationship at work back to a professional relationship?

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/410/what-should-we-do-with-questions-about-personal-dilemmas-with-no-right-answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: You say she affects your manager's opinion about you. Since it affects you professionally, the situation is most decidedly __not__ just personal.

Comment: It's definitely about navigating the workplace for the same reason that seafaring includes navigating around the rocks that could wreck your ship :)

Comment: How are you having dinner alone with your managers assistant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your co-worker is crossing your personal boundaries with her behaviors, so you need to work to re-establish those boundaries. Some things to try:

- Stop spending time with her outside of work. She is behaving in an overly personal way, so you need your relationship to shift to something strictly professional.
- When she says personal things in a professional environment, be prepared to speak up. Keep it short and to the point: "I would prefer it if you did not make personal comments about me at work."
- Avoid her as much as possible. She sounds toxic.
- Don't let her be the determinant of the quality of your relationship with your own manager. Following a negative comment from your co-worker, find a few minutes to speak to your manager about it: "I am concerned Jane's comments might affect the way you view my work. Is there anything I should be concerned about regarding my performance here?"

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd make friends with someone who likes me for however I am, and whose thoughts resonates with mine. Just leave this person and talk, work etc with her like you are just doing your job (i.e. be a professional).

These kind of people are like extra baggage that one can definitely do without. And like i said treat her like you are just doing your work (politely and assertively). Hope this helps.